# Unicode characters does not display in .net

Tags: .net, unicode

I have a table which store some non English letters as varchar in the sql server. When i retrieve the data and show it in a  grid view, it shows the exact character that i stored. But in some machines , the values are displayed as square symbols as if it cant identify the font.

what can i do to make it visible throughout all the machines.

I fill the gridview directly from the query result that fills a DataView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A square indicates that the machine doesn't have a font available that can display the glyph.  Particularly common on XP, it shipped with fonts that had poor glyph coverage.

You'll need to ask the admin to deploy the necessary fonts.  Can't give you a hint, you didn't document the codepoint.  Ask at superuser.com